# xPath with ElementTree (python) to parse XML from string

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I'm using ElementTree to parse some XML retrieved from a website, but somehow I can't see to be able to use ".find" or ".findall". I tried to use ElementTree, and I tired lxml.etree and nothing is working with me. My goal is to retrieve //course from my XML file retrieved from a URL.

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
res = requests.get(COURSES_URL).text #Storing the XML into res
XML = ET.fromstring(res)
print(XML.findall('//COURSE'))
```

COURSES_URL is my own URL which I am retrieving the XML from, and yes it is working since I got the output XML that I want (sample):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated by Oracle Reports version 11.1.2.1.0 -->
<SYRSPOS_REP>
  <LIST_G_PROGRAM>
    <G_PROGRAM>
      <SPRIDEN_ID>U712214</SPRIDEN_ID>
      <STUDENT_NAME>Mark Adam Johns</STUDENT_NAME>
      <SMBPOGN_PIDM>98</SMBPOGN_PIDM>
      <SMBPOGN_REQUEST_NO>46</SMBPOGN_REQUEST_NO>
      <COURSE ID=1411001>PASS</COURSE>
      <COURSE ID=1411023>PASS</COURSE>
      <COURSE ID=1411136>PASS</COURSE>
    </G_PROGRAM>
  </LIST_G_PROGRAM>
</SYRSPOS_REP>
```

Comment: Please post a minimal but complete sample of the XML i.e make sure it includes the target element `<course>` and make sure the entire XML is well-formed (single root element, closing tag, etc.)

Comment: In addition to the previous comment, and taking into account that all tags of your small sample are upper case: did you try "//COURSE"?

Comment: @har07  I have updated the XML to include the minimal XML.

Comment: @Markus yes I did, and I will update the main post to reflect that. Thanks.

Comment: Could it be that you are not paying attention to XML namespaces?

Comment: @thethiny After adding double quotes on the XML attributes and a `.` at the beginning of the XPath, it worked: https://eval.in/958573 . As tomalak suggests, probably there are XML namespaces in the actual XML ?

Comment: @har07 thanks guys I just needed a dot before the double slash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved:
Apparently I had 2 issues.
First of all I can't use `findall` in print since it returns a list, I had to do a for in loop `for i in XML.findall()`, then I print `i.text()`.
Secondly, I had to add a dot after the quotation mark, as in `".//COURSES"`